# Find overlapping price validity dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, overlap, timespan

I am facing a challenge that I just can not master with my limited SQL skills. I hope you can help me. Given I have a table with item prices that are valid for special customers in specified timespans.

Because people sometimes just do not think before entering a new price for a timespan, I have to find out, where there are overlapping timespans for the combination of Item No and Customer No. I just need to find out IF there is an overlap going on, not when the overlap is happening.

I have a table CustomerPrices with data like that:

```
Item No   Customer No     Valid from    Valid to      Price
12345     55544           01.01.2016    31.05.2016    5,66
12345     55544           01.03.2017    01.06.2017    4,55
12345     55544           01.02.2017    01.07.2017    6,41
```

Could you please point me in the right direction?

Best regards and thank you!

Comment: what's your dbms?

Comment: I am using SSMSE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need customer/item pairs with an overlap, then:

```
select distinct custno, itemno
from customerprices cp
where exists (select 1
              from customerprices cp2
              where cp2.custno = cp.custno and cp2.itemno = cp.itemno and
                    cp2.validfrom <= cp.validto and
                    cp2.validto >= cp.validto and
                    (cp2.validfrom <> cp.validfrom or cp2.validto <> cp.validto)
             );
```

What is this logic?  First, it assumes that there are no complete duplicates on the timing.  Second, it checks if there is any overlap -- inclusive of the end pariods.  This should handle any overlap (ABBA, ABAB).

Comment: That was exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    itemno, 
    custno,
    validfrom, 
    validto, 
    price 
from 
    CustomerPrices a
where 
    exists (
        select 1 
        from CustomerPrices b 
        where 
            a.itemno = b.itemno 
            and a.custno = b.custno
            and ((a.validfrom between b.validfrom and b.validto) 
              or (a.validto between b.validfrom and b.validto)) 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can CONVERT entries of type date to an integer representation (see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/04f2098e-9802-4fea-a936-3f988981f8ee/convert-datetime-to-integer?forum=transactsql)). This will allow you to compare your date entries more easily.

Comment: Can you please explain? Date comparison in any compliant dbms is pretty much the same as integer comparison. You use the same syntax and everything. I feel that converting the datatype explicitly is just wasted cycles during coding and execution.

Comment: Thought this would be easier to compare with a sub query, the EXISTS results offered are better.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure,what output you are looking for ?Explain the output.

IT return the last row because its valid from is overlapping with it previous row validto.

```
declare @t table(id int identity(1,1),ItemNo int,CustomerNo int
,Validfrom date,Validto date,Price int)
insert into @t VALUES
(12345,55544, '2016-01-01','2016-05-31',566)
,(12345,55544,'2017-03-01','2017-06-01',455)
,(12345,55544,'2017-02-01','2017-07-01',641)
select t1.*

from @t t
inner join @t t1
 on t.ItemNo=t1.ItemNo
and t.CustomerNo=t1.CustomerNo
where 
 (t1.Validfrom<t.Validto)
 and t1.id-t.id=1
```